# How do you select the text content of a label that wraps an input? (CSS HTML)

Tags: html, css

My label is as follows:

```
 <label for="name">Title: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
```

The label is also a flexbox so that I can align it with the form and set a gap between them:

```
label{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

I set my input box to grow `flex:1` but the issue is that when the label's text content has a space, it automatically wraps it to two lines. If I try to set flex-shrink:0 or hardcode a width in the CSS above, naturally it applies to the whole label block.

Is there a way for me to apply CSS to just the label's text content so that I can stop this text wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the wraping with

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

or you can have the label and input seperate like this

```
<label for="name">Title: </label><input type="text" name="name">
```

and put margin on the label

```
label{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```